# Changing conditions while referring to a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
conditions = [
    (final_dataframe['In stock?'] == 1 & [final_dataframe['qty_total'] < 1]),
    (final_dataframe['In stock?'] == 0 & [final_dataframe['qty_total'] >= 1])
]
t_or_f = ['True', 'False']
final_dataframe['Unlist This']
```

I have this code which is saying if the in stock column = 0 and qty column is less than 1, write true into the new column (unlist this). And if the in stock column = 1 and qty column is >= 1 write false. I just want to update this so the second one will basically say:

If "in stock?" = 0 and qty_total is BETWEEN 1 and 98765 then print False. Any way I can easily update this existing code to do that or something similar enough that numbers higher than 98765 print anything into the new column?

Comment: So you want to de-couple dataframe from the condition? Perhaps use a lambda which takes a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have parentheses placed in your conditions properly. Pandas doesn't like & without proper parentheses.

Next, you could use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to modify your second condition.

With those, your `conditions` will look like:

```py
conditions = [
    (final_dataframe['In stock?'] == 1) & (final_dataframe['qty_total'] < 1]),
    (final_dataframe['In stock?'] == 0) & (final_dataframe['qty_total'].between(1, 98765, inclusive='both'))
]
```